# Retain Data in AppsContext.Instance in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
  using System;

  namespace KfcBoh.Inventory.MobileUi.Models.User
  {
   public sealed class AppsContext
    {
    #region Properties
    private static AppsContext _instance = null;
    private static readonly object SyncLock = new object();
    public List<StorageData> StorageItemsForPreCount { get; set; } = new List<StorageData>();

    #endregion
    public AppsContext()
    {
    }

    public static AppsContext Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                lock (SyncLock)
                {
                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        _instance = new AppsContext();
                    }
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
}
```

`AppsContext.Instance.StorageItemsForPreCount` gets cleared when App is Killed.

How to prevent this data from getting deleted from the list when the app is killed in Xamarin Forms ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a self-defined class, even though it is a singleton,it doesn't do anything to store data on the device,it will be destroyed when the app is killed.

You could convert your `StorageItemsForPreCount` to a json string,then use [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) or [Xamarin.Essentials: Secure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) to store it.And you just need convert the json string to your
`List<StorageData>` again when you want to use it.